# What is this light called, which resembles a spotlight but has a thin blue ring on the edge?

Tags: lighting

I’ve seen this light being used a lot lately in different photos but nobody can tell me what it’s called.
I know it’s a spotlight but what exact one is it that has the thin blue ring around the edge?

[This is an example image showing this light (NSFW)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUeeF.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

The thin blue ring along the edge is very likely an optical aberration of the spot's front lens.These lenses are designed to be cheap, withstand the heat, and do a reasonable job of making light rays parallel, not to be optically accurate (especially if slightly de-focused since the light beam is likely conical here).

Comment: Might want to answer the first question with the term "spot light".

Answer (score 2):

The key characteristic of a spotlight is – light from the lamp radiates out in all directions. The job of the spotlight lens is to alter the path of these light rays so they exit as parallel rays. It’s the shape of the lens (convex) and the density of the glass that does this trick. Now every lens, suffers from defects that impairs it from doing its job. In other words, numerous light rays will not travel the desired path.

These wandering light rays can be devastating. There are 7 major lens errors called aberration.

1. Astigmatism
2. Curvature of Field
3. Distortion
4. Spherical
5. Coma
6. Chromatic Transverse
7. Chromatic Longitudinal

The last two pertain to how the lens changes the direction of the various colored light rays.

Now the lens of the spotlight lamp is quite simple thus it fails to address these aberrations.

Violet / Blue has the shortest wavelengths, the path of these rays are the most refracted (bend inward). Thus, they come to a focus closer to the lens. Whereas the red, and the green, yellow, orange, etc. occupy intermediate positions.

Chromatic aberrations are difficult to mitigate. To correct, the front lens must be comprised to two elements a strong convex paired with a weak concave, both different density glass.

We see this color fringing in the best of optical systems as a rainbow of colors surrounding the outline of objects we image.

Close examination of a spotlight will reveal a rainbow of color fringing. Since the edges of the lens must bend (refract) the light by a greater angle, we see this fringing mostly at the edge of the spot.

Answer (score 2):

> What is this light called, which resembles a spotlight but has a thin blue ring on the edge?

It's called a spotlight.

> I know it’s a spotlight but what exact one is it that has the thin blue ring around the edge?

It's pretty much a standard spotlight. Most of them do the same thing. Depending on how wide it is focused, whether the aperture is wide open or stopped down (most spotlights use an aperture to control brightness), and how far the spotlight is from the thing it is illuminating, it can be thicker or thinner and more saturated (a deeper blue) or less saturated (a lighter blue).

If one is willing to throw enough money at it, one can spend a lot on several corrective lens elements and circular aperture blades to make the ring less evident.

It's due to chromatic aberration which is always more severe on the edge than in the center. CA splits white light into a prism of its component colors. We don't see this rainbow in the middle because all of the rainbows at slightly different positions overlap, giving each place a full set of colors that combine to be white. On the edge we're only seeing the extreme edge of the rainbow. Blue/violet are the shortest wavelengths in the visible spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

The fixture is an [ellipsoidal reflector spotlight](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoidal_reflector_spotlight) (often called a Leeko) with a spherical lens element in the projecting lens. The blue edge is chromatic aberration inherent in the simple lens design typical of the front projecting element.

Higher end ellipsoidals often have more sophisticated aspherical optics (with correspondingly higher prices) to reduce chromatic aberration.

The chromatic aberration is particularly noticeable in the picture because the light is more or less focused on the background due to lack of separation between the subject and the background.

In ordinary theatrical use, aberration would be less noticeable because of intensity falloff and defocusing when the subject is more distant from the background.  Throwing in some blue gelled light from other fixtures and adding texture and color to the background would also help lessen the effect.